# Drawn current of heating elements in parallel won't add up

Tags: current, heat

I have three heating elements (12, 40W) that I want to connect to a single power source (12V, 16A). If I attach one of the heating elements directly, it draws 2,3A @ 12V. But If I attach 3 heating elements in parallel, they draw only 4,3A @ 12V. Can you tell my why its not 2,3A x 3 = 6,9A and how I could achieve that? I am using these [heaters](https://www.banggood.com/de/3-x-12V-40W-6mm-x-20mm-Cartridge-Heater-Reprap-For-3D-Printer-p-1145416.html?gmcCountry=DE&currency=EUR&cur_warehouse=CN&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_elc&utm_content=zouzou&utm_campaign=pla-de-elc2-pc&gclid=CjwKCAjw3qDeBRBkEiwAsqeO7jFpvw8f2Q4sit-OraaPQBhokbMvXSbWelX2U4uWoSuYhPeMeTqBaxoCVyIQAvD_BwE). Thanks for your help, appreciate any hint.

Comment: Have you measured their resistance separately?

Comment: Do all three heat up to the same temperature?   Did you measure after they warmed up or when they were still cold?  Try putting the heaters on ice to make sure they are all on.  One of them probably reached its threshold temperature and turned off.

Comment: Did you measure the voltage with all three heaters connected?  From your numbers, you shouldn't be overloading the power source - but it is always good practice to check that the voltage is really what you expect.

Comment: Yes, the resistance is the same for each heating element (about 5 ohm)

Comment: I measured them at room temperature and all three of them get hot although one seems to gets hotter faster than the others. Yes I have measured the voltage with all three connected as well as each one separate. One more thing I noticed is that the current being drawn is slowly decreasing

Comment: For most materials, resistivity goes up as temperature increases. Did you measure the three together at the same temperature as you measured the single one?

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys I figured it out! Turned out the wires I have been using were just not ment to deliver that much current. Using some proper wires solved the problem. Thanks everyone for your help!